# value of textbox = a variable

Tags: variables, textbox

Good morning.
I have these textbox and I want when I write a number it is attribute to a variable along the script, for this I create a function Onclick = setvalue(). So I want when I click ok the button the variables along the script change to the corresponding value in the textbox.

```
 <form name="myform1" id="population"> 
        Input the number of populations<br />
        <input type="number" name="pop" id="pop" value=pop /><br />
        Input the number of Iterations<br />
        <input type="number" name="Iterations" id="Iterations" value=totalIterations /><br />
        <input type="button" name="b1" id="b1" value="Click to set" onClick="setValue()" /><br /> 
    </form>
```

Comment: I think you need to write this : 
`var iterations = document.getElementById("Iterations").value;` in your setValue() function and for the other textbox.

Comment: I try this way and is ok although when I run the program some errors appears when this variables are used and I d not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

For basic javascript.

```
function setValue(){

//JAVASCRIPT
var iterations= document.getElementById("Iterations").value;

//JQUERY
var iterationsJquery = $("#iterations').value;

console.log(iterations,iterationsJquery);
}
```

This is very basic stuff.

But if your planning to iterate, and create a new element that still holds the value of the variable of your textbox. Use data attributes.

EDIT: on your comment you're saying there is an error? how do you use your variable? Maybe you didn't declare it as global if your trying to access it through another function. Or you didn't pass the value to the other function where you need to use it.